# Sort array by mutiple fields (closest to number)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

**How can I sort a array by two(one) different values?**

So I have a array like this:

```
array(
   array(
      'id' => 10,
      'total' => 38,
      'entry' => 400
   ),
   array(
      'id' => 4,
      'total' => 34,
      'entry' => 3100
   ),
   array(
      'id' => 2,
      'total' => 34,
      'entry' => 3150
   ),
   array(
      'id' => 8,
      'total' => 34,
      'entry' => 2980
   ),
);
```

The array is already sorted by the key `total`, but they all have the same value in `total`. So I need to sort by who is closest to 3000 by `entry`.

**Edit**

The array should be first sorted by `total` and then `entry`, since `entry` is only there so I can differentiate who is the best.

So the array should look like this:

```
array(
  array(
      'id' => 10,
      'total' => 38,
      'entry' => 400
  ),
  array(
      'id' => 8,
      'total' => 34,
      'entry' => 2980
   ),
   array(
      'id' => 4,
      'total' => 34,
      'entry' => 3100
   ),
   array(
      'id' => 2,
      'total' => 34,
      'entry' => 3150
   )
);
```

Comment: usort with comparing abs($v1-3000) and abs($v2-3000)

Comment: @splash58 can you show an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a['total'] == $b['total']) { // Only compare on entry when the totals are the same.
        return abs($a['entry'] - 3000) > abs($b['entry'] - 3000);
    }
    return $a['total'] < $b['total'];
});

print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [total] => 35
            [entry] => 3150
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [total] => 34
            [entry] => 2980
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [total] => 34
            [entry] => 3100
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [total] => 34
            [entry] => 3250
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [total] => 32
            [entry] => 3400
        )

)
```

Here's how it works: it compares the `total`s, but if they're the same, it compares the absolute value of the difference between `entry` and 3000 of both `entry`s.

[eval.in demo](https://eval.in/891612)

Comment: @user2344408 If you have other elements in the array that don't all have the same total, let me know so I can update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I actually have a array with lets say 100+ and it might not be same total

Comment: @user2344408 Ah, ok, I'll update my answer to sort on the total column first, and then then the entry column :)

Comment: Thanks! You are the best :)

Comment: @user2344408 Should total be sorted ascending or descending? And BTW, you might want to update your question :)

Comment: @user2344408 I've updated my answer to compare total first, then entry. Please check :)

Comment: Looks so good and simple! Thank you so much, it looks like it works here also :D